# como puedo modificar un valor en un archivo tipo json

Tags: python, json, archivo, diccionarios, modificaciones

quiero cambiar los datos de los dicionarios anidados, pero cada vez que lo intento se termina eliminando toda la informacion

```
{'856': {'numero': 'C43', 'nombre': 'pera', 'marca': 'edfrf', 'numero de activo': '856', 'ubicacion': 'almacen', 'responsable': 'qqqqqq'}, '2525': {'numero': 'R513', 'nombre': 'llave', 'marca': 'ggg', 'numero de activo': '225', 'ubicacion': 'almacen', 'responsable': 'pepe'}}
```

no estoy muy seguro de como hacer la parte final para que se guarden los nuevos datos en el archivo json, al llamar los datos del archivo como "content" me permite ver los datos y cuando le doy en la opcion de cambiar alguno estos se reflejan en "content" pero cuando intento enviar esos cambios al archivo json no suceden sino que se termina eliminando todo y deja la hoja en blanco

```
import json
file = open('activos.json' , mode='r' , encoding='utf8')
content = json.load(file)
file.close()
buscar = input("buscar por codigo: ")
for clave , valor in content.items():
    if clave == buscar:
        while True:
            datoAcambiar = (input("""Elija el dato que desea cambiar:
            1.nombre
            2.marca 
            3.ubicacion
            4.responsable
            5.numero
            6.salir
            """))
            if datoAcambiar=="1":
                new_equipo = input( "Nuevo nombre: " )  
                content[clave]["nombre"] = new_equipo
            elif datoAcambiar=="2":
                new_marca = input( "Nueva marca: " )
                content[clave]["marca"] = new_marca
            elif datoAcambiar=="3":
                new_ubicacion = input("nueva ubicacion: ")
                content[clave]["ubicacion"] = new_ubicacion
            elif datoAcambiar=="4":
                new_responsable = input("responsable; ")
                content[clave]["responsable"] = new_responsable
            elif datoAcambiar =="5":
                new_numero = input("nuevo serial: ")
                content[clave]["numero"] = new_numero
                                        
            elif datoAcambiar=="6":
                break
            else:
                print("Ingreso una opción no váilda. Intente de nuevo")
                continue
file = open('activos.json' , mode='a' , encoding='utf8')
json.dumps(content, file , ensure_ascii=False)
file.close()
print(content)
```

en la ultima parte lo intente con el "mode" = a  y w pero ninguno de los dos me permite hacer el cambio, por lo cual no estoy seguro en como enviar la información que cambie devuelta al archivo

Comment: ¿Has tratado de usar `w` como `mode` en lugar de `a` (append)? `file = open('activos.json' , mode='a' , encoding='utf8')`

Answer (score 1):

## json.dump vs json.dumps

No estas usando el método correcto para guardar el objeto Python en un archivo.

El método que ocupas para guardar un objeto python en un archivo es `json.dump`

```py
with open('activos.json',"w") as file:
    json.dump(content, file , ensure_ascii=False)
print(content)
```

El método `json.dumps` es para convertir un objeto de Python en un string de Python, por ejemplo:

```py
import json
# Este es un diccionario de Python (también es un objeto):
myobjeto= {"mombre": "Fernando", "edad": 18}

resultado= json.dumps(myobjeto)
print(resultado, type(resultado) )
```

Resultado:

```
{"mombre": "Fernando", "edad": 18} <class 'str'>
```